# Compiling with CLion and libpqxx

Tags: c++, c++11, clion, libpqxx

I'm trying to test a connection to my postgreSQL database. I've installed libpqxx from here [The official C++ client API for PostgreSQL](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx).

I'm using the latest version of **CLion** for my project, **GCC 8.1** on **Fedora 28** OS. and I'm going to use the C++11 standard. When I try to compile my code I get:

```
/usr/local/include/pqxx/internal/statement_parameters.hxx:213:13: error: ‘experimental’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
      const std::experimental::optional<Arg> &arg)
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/pqxx/internal/statement_parameters.hxx:213:35: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
      const std::experimental::optional<Arg> &arg)
                                   ^
/usr/local/include/pqxx/internal/statement_parameters.hxx:213:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘<’ token
  const std::experimental::optional<Arg> &arg)
                                   ^
                                   )
/usr/local/include/pqxx/internal/statement_parameters.hxx:212:40: note: to match this ‘(’
   template<typename Arg> void add_field(
                                        ^
/usr/local/include/pqxx/internal/statement_parameters.hxx:213:35: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
  const std::experimental::optional<Arg> &arg)
```

So I think there is something wrong with my **libpqxx** configuration or my usage of it.

1. Do I have to include some Information on **pqxx** in the **CMakeLists.txt** or does the usage of `#include <pqxx/pqxx>` is enough? Using the `#include <pqxx/pqxx>` doesn't output any unrecognized errors.
2. Do I have to configure the **libpqxx** to use C++11 and reinstall it. If yes, what is the right flag to use for setting a specific C++ standard when executing `./configure`? I didn't find any information on that in the official Site and on the internet.
3. Do I have to add some setting in **CLion** to build my project with C++11?

Comment: The errors are complaining about `experimental::optional` rather than libpqxx, and I think that was part of C++11. Therefore this might help [How to enable C++11 in CLion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317981/how-to-enable-c11-in-clion)

Comment: @acraig5075 I already use the `set(CXX_STANDARD 11)` option in my **CMakeFile**

Comment: @acraig5075 In the end it was the solution I've been searching for.

Comment: I had to use also the instructions here [Allow build to hide std::experimental::optional](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/commit/291db1079f98396b2de4ff9f9adec0044666a905)