# cmake enable g++ -std=c++11

Tags: c++11, cmake

I have a c++ project and I use cmake to build it.
in the c++ code I use std::to_string
and apparently I have to path the command `g++ -std=c++11`to compile it.

I tried :

```
ccmake .. CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -std=c++11
```

but I have an error that it's looking for a folder std=c++11 in the build directory.

How can I enable c++11 using cmake ?

Comment: In the referenced question it is better to use the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28592565/3440745). BTW, it is very easy googled.

Comment: thanks, works perfectly